# Changing cursor shape in PyQGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, cursor, zoom, qgsmapcanvas

I noticed that PyQGIS has `QgsMapToolPan()` and `QgsMapToolZoom()` functions, and the cursor shape on the canvas will change to a hand (for pan), magnifying-glass(+/-) (for zoomIn / zoomOut).

I have a toolbar for Select (arrow icon), Marquee (bounding box icon), besides the Pan, ZoomIn and ZoomOut tool buttons.

Currently, I created the Select & Marquee tools as `QgsMapTool(canvas)` and `setAction` with the appropriately UI widget buttons.

How can I change the cursor shape to an arrow when the Select tool is activated, and cross when the Marquee tool is activated?

(I noted the default cursor shape for `QgsMapTool()` is a Cross icon which I could use for the Marquee tool.)

Answer (score 5):

### For PyQGIS 2:

The mouse cursor can be controlled by calling the `setCursor` method of any `QWidget`:

```py
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

cursor = QCursor()
cursor.setShape(Qt.WhatsThisCursor)
qgis.utils.iface.mainWindow().centralWidget().setCursor(cursor)
```

Or alternatively on the application level:

```
QApplication.instance().setOverrideCursor(cursor)
```

Answer (score 1):

### For PyQGIS 3, using a Python context manager:

It's recommended as it will make sure the cursor is set back in case of error when leaving the block of code.

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt
from qgis.utils import OverrideCursor

with OverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor):
    # Do something here ...
```

Answer (score 0):

### For PyQGIS 3:

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication

QGuiApplication.setOverrideCursor(Qt.WaitCursor)

# do something here ...

QGuiApplication.restoreOverrideCursor()
```