# Editing Cursor for GPS live tracking in QGIS 2.4

Tags: qgis, qgis-2.4, mouse-cursor

I am interested in using QGIS 2.4 for vessel navigation due to its ability to display NOAA vector charts or BSB's as well as user created shapefiles.  I currently oversee a project that requires seafloor object buffers to be displayed so that the vessel can navigate around them during bottom trawl surveys to avoid snagging the net.  I would like to be able to modify the displayed cursor to include a steer whisker akin to what you would see in a vessel chart plotter.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: I imagine it can only be done through coding, in which case [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42542/how-to-change-cursor-shape-in-pyqgis) might help.